# Let $f(x) = \tanh(x) - \frac{1}{x}$ find $\lim_{t \to 0} t f^{-1}(t) $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits

Consider the following function
\begin{align}
f(x) = \tanh(x) - \frac{1}{x}
\end{align}

We are interested in finding the following limit
\begin{align}
\lim_{t \to 0} t f^{-1} \left( \sqrt{1-t} \right)=??
\end{align}
where $f^{-1}$ is the functional inverse.

It's a difficult limit.  I think I can show that $f^{-1}(t) \le c(t) \frac{ t}{1-t^2} $
where $2 \le c(t)  \le 3$, which implies that
\begin{align}
\lim_{t \to 0} t f^{-1} \left( \sqrt{1-t} \right) = \lim_{t \to 0} c(t) 
\end{align}
But I don't have a good approximation for $c(t)$.

Comment: Why not consider $\lim_{x \to \infty} \frac{ f^{-1} \left( \sqrt{1-1/x} \right)}{x}$ and apply  l'Hôpital's rule?

Comment: @user69559 Sure, but how would this help? The inverse will still be in the expression.  And we will get similar terms were you need to l'hopital again.  Unless I am missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $x=f^{-1}(\sqrt{1-t}).$ Then
$t=1-f(x)^2.$ When $t\to 0, $ then $\sqrt{1-t}\to 1,$ and consequently $x\to \infty .$
Therefore
$$\lim_{t\to 0}tf^{-1}(\sqrt{1-t})=\lim_{x\to \infty }[1-f(x)^2]x\\ =
\lim_{x\to \infty}[x-xf(x)]\,\lim_{x\to \infty }[1+f(x)]$$ The second limit is equal $2.$
Next $$x-xf(x)]=1+x(1-\tanh x)=1+{2x\over e^{2x}+1}\underset{x\to \infty}{\longrightarrow}  1$$
Thus the result is equal $2.$

**Remark** The last limit does not require the l'Hospital rule. Let $n=\lfloor 2x\rfloor.$ Then
$$0\le {2x\over e^{2x}+1}\le  {n+1\over e^n}\le {n+1\over 2^n}\le {n+1\over {n\choose 2}}\le {2x+2\over (2x-1)(x-1)}$$